# Can not Receive SMS from Sender With SenderID

Tags: sms, twilio

I am trying to test a service. I need Twilio to receive SMS from specific SMS service provider. When the sender sends with a number I can receive the message. But when the sender user SenderID like 'RZ SMS' I can not receive the message. The structure of the message in both situations is the same.

Has anybody faced this problem before?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It is not possible to respond to SMS messages sent from an alphanumeric ID. You also cannot initiate messages to an alphanumeric ID. Please see more details on alphanumeric sender IDs here: https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181348-Getting-started-with-Alphanumeric-Sender-ID

Comment: Hi Philnash, Actually the problem is with Receiving not Sending or replying messages. I can not Recieve any message from the sender. It seems there is a problem with filtering or spamming the messages

Comment: Oh, you can't receive a message in Twilio if the sender uses an alphanumeric sender ID when they send it to you? That doesn't seem right. I'd get in contact with the [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) team and they will be able to look into this for you.

Comment: Seems still a problem https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223133447-Not-Receiving-Incoming-SMS-and-MMS-Messages-on-Twilio-Phone-Number
Quote :
```
Are you expecting to receive SMS from an Alphanumeric Sender ID?
At this time, Twilio does not support receiving incoming SMS from external Alphanumeric Sender IDs. An Alphanumeric Sender ID is not a phone number, but a string of letters and numbers, usually spelling the name of the business or entity sending the messages.
```

Comment: Oh, well, that is the answer then. You can't receive a message from an alphanumeric sender ID on a Twilio phone number.